# you have chosen to open which is a : PHTML file FireFox error

Tags: php, firefox

I followed this tutorial to start working with PHP and netbeans

http://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/ubuntu_php_netbeans

and as I have created a .php file which has

```
<?php
     phpinfo();
?>
```

as the only content, but what I refresh the page it says (in FF)

you have chosen to open

which is a : PHTML file
from : `http://127.0.0.1` etc..

that is this error and how can i fix this. (I'm running on ubuntu and I have zend studio installed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the following worked :

1. install libapache2-mod-php5
2. restart the server

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was .htaccess in site directory

rewrite condition was

```
<   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
<   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

instead of standart one

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

in this case this was drupal project

..end don't forget to clear your cache
http://kb.iu.edu/data/ahic.html#fire35w

Answer (score 0):

It is a .htaccess problem - just delete it and create a new one or edit the actual one to reflect the url of the website.